# Weird shadows when rendering hair strands in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, hair

I made a hair particle system and converted it into mesh with hair tool addon. The object has large numbers of transparent planes, and I raised the value of transparency max bounces to 80, which erased most of the ugly shadows. But there were still some dark shadows on the hair, raising the bounces to 1024 still could not erase them. I noticed that these shadows probably appeared where hair cards overlapped, but I can't avoid overlapping or clipping in this model, and the render result in EEVEE seems OK, at least no weird shadows, so I think there is also a way to solve this in Cycles?
[image]

And this is what it looks like in solid viewport:[image]

I found the reason is that I gave the hair a transmission value of 0.1 yesterday... turn it down to 0 and the shadows are gone. Transmission should be added with an alpha map I think.

Comment: You are using alpha and I have seen this few times, this can happen when your faces that has alpha overlaps, 2 faces are in the exactly same spot(parts of them) and that overlapping might be the cause of that weird shadow

Comment: @MikoCGthx for the reply. I used to merge all the vertices by distance to see if this can help, but shadows still occurs. Doesn't merging vertices help solve the overlapping problem you mentioned? Or I have to manually check the geometry of the model.

Comment: merging solves duplicated vertices and disconnected vertices but not overlapping faces

Comment: @MikoCG After countless times of checking, I found the reason is that I gave the hair a transmission value of 0.1 yesterday... turn it down to 0 and the shadows are gone:(